# Remove bootstrap multi-select property and enable single selection

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select dropdown with multiple selection and I used bootstrap-multiselect JavaScript plugin to include checkbox selection.
My requirement is want give a button enable/disable multiple selection. By default onload multiple selection will be available when user click the  enable/disable multiple selection remove the multiple selection property.

```
<div class="row">
    <select name="select[]" multiple="multiple" id="select" class="multiselect">
        //options goes here
    </select>
    <select name="select2[]" multiple="multiple" id="select2" class="multiselect">
        //options goes here
    </select>
</div>
<button type="button" id="button">Enabel/Disable multiselection</button>
```

Tried by removing multiple attribute but it is not succeed.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#select").removeAttr("multiple");
})
```

Problem is plugin don't have any inbuilt functionality for my requirement.

For multiple select lists with class name it will creating multiple buttons.
For example : like the image attached. (In the image the 'And' dropdown is not a muliselect dropdown)

I have one select(not multiselect) box at top from that selected option I will create related multiple select dropdowns dynamicaly which are needs to be multi selected

[image]

[image]

Comment: then you can use simple select option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var selectedMenu=[];

var defaultOptions=[
    {name:'And',value:'none'},
    {name:'Department',value:'Department'},
    {name:'Category',value:'Category'},
    {name:'ItemType',value:'ItemType'},
    {name:'Publisher',value:'Publisher'},
];


var arr_Category=[
     {'name':'Category1','id':'cat1'},
     {'name':'Category2','id':'cat2'},
     {'name':'Category3','id':'cat3'},
     {'name':'Category4','id':'cat4'}
 ];


var arr_Department=[
     {'name':'departments 1','id':1},
     {'name':'departments 2','id':2},
     {'name':'departments 3','id':3},
     {'name':'departments 4','id':4}
 ];
 
 
 var arr_ItemType=[
     {'name':'itemtypes 1','id':1},
     {'name':'itemtypes 2','id':2},
     {'name':'itemtypes 3','id':3},
     {'name':'itemtypes 4','id':4}
 ];

 var arr_Publisher=[
     {'name':'publisher 1','id':1},
     {'name':'publisher 2','id':2},
     {'name':'publisher 3','id':3},
     {'name':'publisher 4','id':4}
 ];


$(document).on('change','#checkbox',function(){  
           if($(this).is(':checked')){
             $('.form-check-label').text('Multiple Options');
             for(var i=1;i<defaultOptions.length;i++){
                $('.'+defaultOptions[i].value).attr('multiple','multiple');
                $('.'+defaultOptions[i].value).multiselect('rebuild');
             }
          }else{
           $('.form-check-label').text('Single Options');
              for(var i=0;i<defaultOptions.length;i++)
              {
                    $('.'+defaultOptions[i].value).removeAttr('multiple');
                    $('option', $('.'+defaultOptions[i].value)).each(function(element) {            
                        $(this).removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);
                        });
                    $('.'+defaultOptions[i].value).multiselect('rebuild');
              }
          }
       });

    
$(document).on('change','.main_menu',function(){
     
     
     var SelectedValue=$(this).val();
     
    
       if(selectedMenu.indexOf(SelectedValue)==-1){
         selectedMenu.push(SelectedValue); 
         var options='';
        
         if(SelectedValue=='Category'){
         
            for(var i=0;i<arr_Category.length;i++){
               options=options+'<option value="'+arr_Category[i].id+'">'+arr_Category[i].name+'</option>';
            }
         }else if(SelectedValue=='Department'){
            for(var i=0;i<arr_Department.length;i++){
               options=options+'<option value="'+arr_Department[i].id+'">'+arr_Department[i].name+'</option>';
            }
         }else if(SelectedValue=='ItemType'){
            for(var i=0;i<arr_ItemType.length;i++){
               options=options+'<option value="'+arr_ItemType[i].id+'">'+arr_ItemType[i].name+'</option>';
            }
         }else if(SelectedValue=='Publisher'){
            for(var i=0;i<arr_Publisher.length;i++){
               options=options+'<option value="'+arr_Publisher[i].id+'">'+arr_Publisher[i].name+'</option>';
            }
         }
         
           var SelectDiv= '<select class="'+SelectedValue+'" name="'+SelectedValue+'" multiple="multiple">'+options+'</select>';
           var AndOptions='';

           for(var i=0;i<defaultOptions.length;i++){
               AndOptions=AndOptions+'<option value="'+defaultOptions[i].value+'">'+defaultOptions[i].name+'</option>';
           }
           
         var AndSelectDiv= '<select class="main_menu">'+AndOptions+'</select>';
          var tr1='<tr><td>'+SelectedValue+'</td><td>'+SelectDiv+'</td></tr>';
          var tr2='<tr class="bg-dark"><td colspan="2">'+AndSelectDiv+'</td></tr>'
           
          $('#tableBody').append(tr1+tr2);
          $('.'+SelectedValue).multiselect();
       }
    
});


$(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
   alert($("form").serialize());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<form >
<table class="table table-hover table-borderd">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr><th colspan="2">

<!--MAIN MENU-->
<select class="main_menu">
    <option value="none">Select One</option>
    <option value="Department">Department</option>
    <option value="Category">Category</option>
    <option value="ItemType">ItemType</option>
    <option value="Publisher">Publisher</option>
   
</select>

</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tableBody">

</tbody>
<tfoot class="bg-warning">
<tr>
<td>Enable / Disable</td>
<td>
<div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="form-check-input" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox"> </label>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" type="button">GET ALL INPUTS</button></td></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Its good and also right solution. But I have multiple select list of same type around 8 to 9. So I want work on 'class' name of select elements and not id

Comment: When I use 'class' name it is appending the same multisect button to the existing select list (multiple times)

Comment: You want to handle multiple dropdown with single checkbox ?

Comment: Yes, and I have edited the question, Please review once.

Comment: I don't understand from image , please tell me from where you handle all these dropdowns ?

Comment: from which button ?

Comment: button means same that checkbox enable/disable

Comment: yes , same that checkbox enable/disable , where it is in picture ?

Comment: Wait I will upload full image.

Comment: I have changed the image, Please review

Comment: I will wait for your answer.

Comment: Mahantesh , please upvote and accept answer if it is useful to you

Comment: Thank you Saurabh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171676/discussion-between-mahantesh-and-saurabh-mistry).